# K-th Smallest in Lexicographical Order

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

Given integers n and k, find the lexicographically k-th smallest integer in the range from 1 to n.

Note: 1 ≤ k ≤ n ≤ 109.

Example:

Input:
n: 13   k: 2

Output:
10

Explanation:
The lexicographical order is [1, 10, 11, 12, 13, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], so the second smallest number is 10.

I have written a code which works fine but when I give very high input it takes a lot of time to execute and hence time out. Could some one please suggest me how i can make it more efficient.

Thanks!!

```
public class Solution {

class MyComp implements Comparator<Integer>{
    @Override
    public int compare(Integer n1, Integer n2) {
        return  String.valueOf(n1).compareTo(String.valueOf(n2));
    }
}

public int findKthNumber(int n, int k) {
    if(n==0 || k ==0 || k > n) return 0;
    int[] tracker = new int[9];
    Arrays.fill(tracker,0);


    Map<Integer,TreeSet<Integer>> map = new HashMap<Integer,TreeSet<Integer>>();
    for(int i =1;i<=n;i++){
        String prefix = String.valueOf(i);
        int currIndex = Integer.parseInt(prefix.substring(0,1));
        //Update count
        tracker[currIndex-1] = tracker[currIndex-1] + 1;
        if(map.containsKey(currIndex)){
             TreeSet<Integer> set = map.get(currIndex);
             set.add(i);
             map.put(currIndex,set);
        }else{
            TreeSet<Integer> set = new TreeSet<Integer>(new MyComp());
            set.add(i);
            map.put(currIndex,set);
        }

    }

    // counter to check the if we reach near by K
    int count =1;
    for(int i=0;i<9 ;i++ ){
        int lookUp = i+1;
        int val = tracker[i];
        if( count + map.get(lookUp).size() > k){
            for(int res : map.get(lookUp)){
                if(count == k) return res;
                count++;
            }
        }
        count = count + map.get(lookUp).size();
    }

    return 0;

}

}
```

Comment: Why is the fact that it's lexicographic order make it unique? Why not look at the code for efficient order statistics, and using  lexicographic order for comparison?

Comment: the TLE is because of the large N. Given the large N, you should be looking at a log N solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use QuickSort for finding location. That will give you nlogn but will be much quicker n simpler.

Psudo code
-> pick random number of out list. 
-> put all element lesser than that one side,higher than that number  other side.
->if the number of lesser elements are k-1, you got the answer. 
->if lesser elements are less than k-1, apply same algo on right side. 
-> if lesser numbers of elements are greater than k, apply same algo on left side.

You can do this inplace
Best time complexity is o (1)
Worst time complexity is o (n*n)
But it gives very stable performance for multiple iteration
Random nature works on all sort of data

Let me know if any of the steps are not clear :)

Comment: Thanks! it helped!

Comment: note: you can use Quicksort's close cousin Quickselect to improve average runtime from nlogn to simply n. The recursive formula for quickselect is T(n) = T(n/2) + O(n)

Answer (score 0):

For such small numbers you could generate all Strings in an array, sort it and return the k-th entry:

```
String[] arr = new String[n];
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
  arr[i] = String.valueOf(n + 1);
Arrays.sort(arr);
return Integer.parseInt(arr[k - 1]);
```

It seems to be much easier than counting to the k-th entry. You don't need to sort the whole array, because you only need to find the k-th smallest entry, anyway for those small numbers it doesn't matter.

Or even better use an integer array and the comparator you already created:

```
Integer[] arr = new Integer[n];
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
  arr[i] = i + 1;
Arrays.sort(arr, MyComp);
return arr[k - 1].intValue();
```